# VMWare Tools for Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, virtualization, vmware-tools

I am using VMWare tools for Ubuntu Hardy, but for some reason `vmware-install.pl` finds fault with my LINUX headers. The error message says that the "address space size" doesn't match.

To try and remediate, I have resorted to `vmware-any-any-update117`, and am now getting the following error instead:

```
In file included from include/asm/page.h:3,
       from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/common/hostKernel.h:56,
       from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/common/task.c:30:
include/asm/page_32.h: In function ‘pte_t native_make_pte(long unsigned int)’:
include/asm/page_32.h:112: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
include/asm/page_32.h:112: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
include/asm/page_32.h:112: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
include/asm/page_32.h:112: error: expected `;' before ‘}’ token
```

Can anyone help me make some sense of this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link as it helped me install the tools in one of my vms. http://diamondsw.dyndns.org/Home/Et_Cetera/Entries/2008/4/25_Linux_2.6.24_and_VMWare.html

Comment: This solution requires some VMWare CD-ROM. I am only using the free VMWare player and could not try this. Anyway, this looks like the correct answer so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

This error ofter occurs because incompatibility of VMWare Tools Version and recent Kernels (You can test it using older Kernels). Sometimes you can fix some thing with patches all over the internet, but I prefer to downgrade my kernel or don't using latest distribution's version in VMWare. It can be really annoying. Another problem you may have is with your mouse pointer in X Windows, like if it was a inch to left or below than it really shows.

About vmware-any-any-update117, it's a patch to VMWare running under linux, usually Workstation version. It won't have effect in Tools.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off using the VMWare Tools .rpm file instead of the install script on Ubuntu.  Alien is a program that will [let you turn a .rpm into a Ubuntu-friendly .deb package](http://ubuntu.wordpress.com/2005/09/23/installing-using-an-rpm-file/).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard a lot of good things about VirtualBox from Sun. If you get fed up with VMWare, it's worth a look.